# Animate Render Effects in JavaFX

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I am building a JavaFX Application that is supposed to run on my RaspberryPi that has a 7" display attached.
For better styling I am trying to animate a `javafx.scene.effect.GaussianBlur`-Effect.

I got it "working" although the performance is pretty bad (low FPS during animation) at the moment (on my laptop, not even speaking of the Pi). See code below.

Is there an more performant way of doing this? Or are these Effects just not supposed to be animated?

```
GaussianBlur blur = new GaussianBlur(0);
backgroundPane.setEffect(blur);
DoubleProperty value = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
value.addListener((observable, oldV, newV)->
{
     blur.setRadius(newV.doubleValue());
});

Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(value, 30);
final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), kv);
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
timeline.play();
```

FYI: The `bakcgroundPlane` is at this stage just a Pane with a Background image added via CSS:

```
.background
{
    -fx-background-image: url("images/bg.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;
    -fx-background-size: 800 480;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
}
```

EDIT:
The problem doesn't seem to be related to the CSS. It still occures, when I set the image in the FXML...

Comment: Is there any specific reason you define a DoubleProperty with a changeListener that you animate that forces the change on the radius? Use the radiusProperty on the GaussianBlur directly.

Comment: You will have a better chance of getting assistance if you supply an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I know your current question has enough information that somebody could replicate it, but currently it is more work for somebody to do so than it would be to just copy and paste minimal, complete, working, compilable code to their machine.  If potential answerers need to do more work to replicate your issue, then your chance of getting good answers diminishes.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to [enable caching](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#cacheProperty) and [set the cache hint to speedy](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#cacheHintProperty)?

Those usually have a massive impact on performance. On one of my little jfx games it was the difference between "playable" and single digit fps values.